# How to skip HttpInterceptor(interceptAfter) for a response in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

This is my current interceptor for the response, I don't want this method to be called after getting response from a specific request -

```
public interceptAfter(response: InterceptedResponse): InterceptedResponse {
        if(response.response.status == 0){
            // CORS error
            location.href="/abc/assets/sessionTimeoutError.html";
        }
        else if(response.response.status == 302 || response.response.status==401){
            if(response.response.url && response.response.url.indexOf('/xyz/')==-1){
                location.href="/abc/assets/sessionTimeoutError.html";
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```